# Adding input to array with sentinel

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I'm trying to add doubles into an array and when the user enters 0, the loops should stop. I'm not getting the program to stop when 0 is entered, it just keeps continuing asking for input. I already have the scanner and such declared. Also, when I can get the array to stop, the last value entered prints out to all the elements of the array.

```
System.out.println("Enter some numbers; 0 to quit");

    //condition for our sentinel
    boolean done = false;

    while (!done){
        //value to be added into array
        double value = in.nextInt();

        //condition to end the while loop
        if (value == 0){
            break;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
            nums[i] = in.nextDouble();


        }

    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums));
```

Comment: What's the size of `nums`? You're *only* checking the first value entered in each "batch" - and you're then ignoring that value if it's not 0.

Comment: `double value = in.nextInt();` This looks interesting............ I think you should re-think that line in particular. Also, unless you prompt the user for how many numbers they want to input (which isn't the case) you don't really know the size of the array before you start looping. I suggest you use some sort of `Collection`.

Comment: Perhaps an `ArrayList` using the `Double` class. That collection is expandable, which is great for the unknown number of doubles they will enter, but can't hold primitives so you will need to use the wrapper class.

Comment: nums has a size of 100